# regex to ignore patterns when after a given characterr

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I'm trying to discover a pattern (in a Ruby source code file) but ignore that pattern if found in an inline comment (i.e., after a `#` character).

For instance, given this text

`foo.bar   foo foo::bar #     foo.bar foo::bar`

I'd like the first (`foo.bar`) and third (`foo::bar`) case of `foo` to be captured and the rest ignored (the second doesn't have an immediately trailing `.` or `::`, and the fourth and fifth appear after a `#` and so should be ignored.

For this text,

`foo.bar   foo foo::bar`

it should still pick up the first and third ones the same way (since there is no comment to ignore).

I have various techniques that get at pieces of this, but nothing that meets all cases.  Lookbehind is promising but can't handle variable length in my regex dialect (Ruby).

Therefore, `((?<!\#.*)foo[\.|:{2}])` won't work because it's variable length (and, as written, would only exclude the first instance after the `#` anyway)

`(.+?(?=#))` was promising too, and so I tried `((foo(\.|\:{2})).+)?(?=\#)` and that's close but doesn't see to distinguish that there are 2 `foo`s after the first one.  The match group just returns `foo.bar   foo foo::bar`, but it does appropriately ignore anything after the `#`.  I'm pretty sure it's the `.+` that causes the poor distinction but other amendments to this don't seem to bring me closer.

Clearly, I'm not getting how to go after this and beginning to wonder if it's possible.

[edit: added second example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't work in Ruby, but from your description it sounds like Ruby doesn't support unbounded quantifiers in lookbehinds. That certainly makes it more difficult. You can, however, take advantage of unbounded lookaheads. You can have a regex that check for `foo_bar`s that don't have inline comments:

```
^[^#]*foo(?:\.|::)bar(?=[^#]*$)
```

...and a regex that checks for `foo_bar`s that do have inline comments:

```
foo(?:\.|::)bar(?=[^#]*#)
```

...and just put them both together with an alternation:

```
foo(?:\.|::)bar(?=[^#]*#)|^[^#]*foo(?:\.|::)bar(?=[^#]*$)
```

Comment: Good idea!  I had the two cases working separately but didn't think of alternation in putting such a "large" pair together.  I'll try that, thx!

Comment: You did one thing I want to be sure I understand.  The `?=[^#]*`in both clauses is to assure that a comment is not encountered before the `$` or the first `#`, correct?  I tried `?=.*#` but that captured too much.  I also tried `*[$|#]` for the following portion and it didn't work either. Could you explain a bit more or direct me to an appropriate resource?  Thank you!

Comment: Correct. The dot-star is problematic because dot matches anything, and "anything" includes `#`. You could mitigate this by using a non-greedy dot-star (`.*?`). Either the "not hash" or non-greedy dot-star should work--it's a matter or preference.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense -- I need to get handier with the greedy behavior.  So to capture, I just need to wrap `foo` in parentheses, but then I noticed that without the inline comment, capturing didn't work with to pick up the individual instances (using `(foo)(?:\.|::)bar(?=[^#]*#)|^[^#]*(foo)(?:\.|::)bar(?=[^#]*$)`)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby's regex implementation. You'd need to consult the documentation to see how capture groups work. In engines I've used, you typically get all of the capture groups back from the engine, but the ones that didn't participate in the match would just be empty. Just keep in mind that (AFAIK) capture groups are number from left to right, with nested groups being numbered prior to right-most groups. So in your pattern, the first `(foo)` is capture group 1 and the second `(foo)` is capture group 2. Regardless of which on matches, they are still 1 and 2, respectively.

Comment: Of course, this is assuming Ruby handles groups in this way.

Comment: I'm using rubular.com to test with, so I'll just play more with it in the actual code.  Thanks for getting me this far!